# How to customise UITableView

Tags: xcode4, uitableview

Actually I'm trying to implement different images in different rows in UITableView.
by creating a new UITableViewCell I tried a lot to implement this but i failed.I need to set two images and a label in each row.
How can it be done?
And i have to get the image in next page using navigation controller...
please specify me the codes and explain.I couldn't understand it otherwise.
Thanks for your kind informative answers...

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        sampletable1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sampletable1" owner:nil options:nil];
            for (UIView *view in views) {
                if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (sampletable1*)view;


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do you keep the images and the text to be put into the label?  What are the properties in the `sampletable1` object that you want to set?

Comment: i have created a group called images. And there is no property added in sampletable1.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "group".  If your custom cell doesn't have any properties, what **does** it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need.[Subclassing UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12). The sample shown has two images in there. You can use the same technique to add one more

Comment: actually i m not using storyboard application

Comment: "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
)"actually  what this means?